# Controlling queryset after filtering | Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to customize the Django Interface.
I have a CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) which has a foreignkey to self, every Category can have SubCategories from the same table.

Every category which has subcategory will be shown as inlines.
Basically on the main Categories queryset I want to show those who's Parent = 0 so I overrided get_queryet to this:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        qs = super(CategoryAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs

    company = CompanyUsers.objects.filter(UserId = request.user.id) #not relevant
    companyid = company.values_list('CompanyId', flat=True) #not relevant
    qs = Category.objects.filter(CompanyId = companyid, Parent = 0) 
    return qs
```

Now when a user picks one of the Categories, the inlines are NOT filtered by that Parent = 0 but when clicking to **change** them I got the error:

"Category object with primary key 'x' does not exist"

Any Ideas on how to filter only on the main Categories queryset?

Note: when removing the "Parent = 0" the error disappears.

Note 2: Could be useful to know which instance was clicked. I know it's possible by overriding get_formset but unfortunately get_queryset is called before get_formset :(

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

As parent refers to Category objects, why use 0 and not None instead? Parent must be an object not an integer.

1. Rename your attributes. CompanyId, Parent must become companyId, parent
2. In your Category Class declare parent as:

   parent = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, default = None)

Only children categories will have a parent relationship, if a Category is parent then parent will be None. Then, when you want to get parent categories you will filter your query like:

```
Category.objects.filter(companyId = companyid, parent = None)
```

Also, parent will be a Category object not an integer.

Comment: Parent refers to PKs in the table and therefore cannot be none. Also, I dont see how this is solving my problem.

Comment: Why a foreign key cannot be null?

Comment: You can see the updated answer for more information.

Comment: Because I dont want any possibility to add a category without a parent. I tried your solution and the results are the same. I believe this can be solved with a condition. Thanks anyway